# oracle in out pl sql package in python procedure call error

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

This is pl/sql code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SALES_PHARMA_19.PKG_DIL_ABCD
IS
   TYPE DIL10001_REC IS RECORD
   (
      DILCOLM_01   NUMBER,
      DILCOLM_02   NUMBER,
      DILCOLM_03   NUMBER,
      DILCOLM_04   NUMBER
   );

   TYPE RC_DIL_10001 IS REF CURSOR
      RETURN DIL10001_REC;

   TYPE DIL10001_TAB IS TABLE OF DIL10001_REC
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   PROCEDURE PRC_DIL10001 (P_REF_DIL001   IN OUT RC_DIL_10001,
                           P_PERREQ_BY    IN     NUMBER,
                           P_UD_REQ_BY    IN     VARCHAR2,
                           P_DESIGCODE    IN     VARCHAR2--,
                     --      P_SFRMST_DT  IN     DATE,
                     --      P_SENDTO_DT  IN     DATE
                     );
                          
END;
/
```

This the body of the package:

```
PROCEDURE PRC_DIL10001 (P_REF_DIL001   IN OUT RC_DIL_10001,
                       P_PERREQ_BY    IN     NUMBER,
                       P_UD_REQ_BY    IN     VARCHAR2,
                       P_DESIGCODE    IN     VARCHAR2--,
                 --      P_SFRMST_DT    IN     DATE,
                 --      P_SENDTO_DT    IN     DATE
                 )
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN P_REF_DIL001 FOR
     SELECT 4 DILCOLM_01,
            2 DILCOLM_02,
            1 DILCOLM_03,
            1 DILCOLM_04
       FROM DUAL;
END;
```

This is my Python code:

```
def data(request):
userpwd = "__"
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user", userpwd, "192.168.0.1:1501/orcl")
curs = connection.cursor()
record = curs.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.NUMBER, [1, 2, 3, 4])
t = [0, '1', '2']

k = curs.callproc("PKG_DIL_ABCD.PRC_DIL10001", [record, t])

for i in record.getvalue():
    print(i)
```

This is the given error:

> ```
> NotSupportedError at /data/
> element 1 value is not the same type as previous elements
> Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/
> Django Version:   3.1.3
> Exception Type:   NotSupportedError
> Exception Value:  
> element 1 value is not the same type as previous elements
> Exception Location:   D:\s h o w n o k\Practice_Project\oracle_api\o_api\myapp\views.py, line 31, in data
> Python Executable:    C:\Users\ATI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.7.2
> ```

Comment: Reviewing: Just for completeness you could pose the question "What is the cause of this error", but on the other hand that is pretty obvious... I think this Q is OK.

Comment: "element value is not the same type as previous elements": is there in your code a list where not all of the values have the same type?

Comment: Can you edit the question by adding body of the package ..?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have this:

```
t = [0, '1', '2']
```

Note that the first element is an integer and the remaining elements are strings. They must be of the same type.

In addition, records must be handled as shown in [this sample](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/PLSQLRecord.py).

Comment: after editing to t=[0, 1, 2] it gives me this error: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRC_DIL10001'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: See additional information in answer -- records are handled differently from arrays.